# Import File Names to Excel Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to implement a command button in my excel sheet that will prompt the user to select the files he wants to load before loading the selected files into the specified cells. So far I have tried using the following code but to no avail. I have been getting a `type 13` error

```
Sub check11()
Dim FileName() As Variant
Dim f As String
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim rng As Variant

rng = ActiveCell.Address
f = Application.GetOpenFilename("TXT File (*.txt), *.txt")
For i = 0 To 1
    FileName(f) = j
    Range(rng).Value = j
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: there are lot of errors in your code. First and most important: with Application.GetOpenFilename("TXT File (*.txt), *.txt") you can NOT select multiple files as far as I know. So the entire rest of your code doesn't make sense at all (even if it would be correct).

Comment: @cboden if you specify Multiselect:=true then you can select multiple files. More info in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`GetOpenFileName` doesn't work in the way you have coded it. You can't select multiple files (as far as I'm aware) so the loop you run is redundant. The function will return either `False` if the user hits Cancel or the name of the file as a string. You ought to test for the Cancel case within your code.

I can't see the purpose of your loop or why you're selecting the offset cell. I think it might be a development error so I've just disregarded it.

Below is some code that shows you how the `GetOpenFileName` function could work in your context:

```
Sub check11()
    Const TARGET_COL As String = "A" 'adjust letter for your column
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    'Find the next blank cell in target column
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set cell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, TARGET_COL).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Open the file dialog window
    selectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    'Check if user hit cancel
    If selectedFile = False Then Exit Sub

    'Write the file name
    cell.Value = selectedFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inccorect acces to `Application.GetOpenFilename` first of all you need to set `MultiSelect` to true so you will be able to select multiple files. Then this function will return array which you can loop. In loop i spliting filepath by "\" and with knowledge that filename is always last, i just write filename into cell.

```
Sub check11()

Dim filePath() As Variant
Dim i As Long

filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("TXT File (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)
For i = 1 To UBound(filePath)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Split(filePath(i), "\")(UBound(Split(filePath(i), "\")))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Lubos! the code seems to be working fine now with some minor edits.

Comment: however a type mismatch error props up when I try to cancel selecting the files.

Comment: so just add minor update. after assign value to filePath just check value and then exit sub. it isnt so hard